# Ubuntu 14.04.04 on iMac: No Sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, mac

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on my iMac late 2013. No sound is generated except for a few applications.

I manged to get sound output on Totem video player by choosing "AC3 pass-through" on it, but the most media players don't have this option.

I checked alsamixer configurations, but it seems configured properly.

How can I enable sound output for speakers/headphones?
Here is the summary of my iMac hardware configurations.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pKDii8l7-Azasqoyo2n_XJgnzg2JN1FgQIJFCzncJAs/pub

Answer (score 0):

I Googled and found a workaround. This enables speaker output, but still I get no sound from the headphone jack.

[Intel_iMac - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac)

**Sound**

If you have an aluminum iMac and you do not have sound :

1. Open `/etc/modprobe.d/options`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/options
   ```
2. Add `options snd-hda-intel model=imac24` to the file and save changes with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and exit with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
3. Reboot.